# Combining a cms and an mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, content-management-system

I am trying to build an app which has lot of content to be displayed too. So basically I wanted to know that is it a good idea if I try combining a cms & an mvc. I have worked independently on various cms's & mvc's. If I use both together in an app, would there be any conflicting parameters & is it a good idea to use both together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no *"various mvc's"*. MVC is a design pattern, which separated lets you separate business logic from presentation. Read : [**UI Architectures**](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) *by Martin Fowler*. I get a feeling that with "mvc" you (mis)understand "MVC frameworks", which are completely different thing, and more often then not, are not really implementing that pattern.

It is possible (and many choose) to build CMS based on MVC pattern and design principles.

But it is **not possible** to magically copy-paste together a random MVC framework and random content management system.

The best you could do would be to leave CMS for site administration, and create a separate front-end, which is based on MVC. Either with or without framework.

Comment: yes, by mvc I meant mvc framework.. btw thanks for the really nice link on ui architectures.. :)

Answer (score 0):

actually, I think you should build a CMS controller / model  / view.

So if you theoretically have some controller method:

```
class Pages_Controller extends Controller {
    function viewPage( $id ) {
        get_db_content($id);
    }
}
```

and use your router to clean up the url. It seems easy in theory.

If you can successfully do it that way, you're going to avoid a lot of the issues that typically come along with trying to combine two frameworks.

Comment: so basically u mean to say I build it in a cms & just use an mvc for querying the database & routing the urls?

Comment: opposite. use your MVC to create a controller and model that serves up dynamic content from a database.

Comment: you'll understand better if you really understand what a CMS is doing -- its serving up content dynamically. And there is an edit page somewhere that you can edit content without the use of coding. so as long as you connect a database to some controller method, and then also make an edit method, you are literally inventing a CMS via MVC